# MissingMethodException when running a unit test that uses FSharp.Data

Tags: f#, f#-data, missingmethodexception

I have a NUnit unit test that is written in a normal F# library but targets F# code in a Portable Class Library.

When I run this test (in Visual Studio 2013), I get the following exception:

```
Result Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found:
 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1<System.IO.TextReader> FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntime(System.Boolean, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)'.
```

This is what I have in my app.config in the Portable Class Library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is what I have in the app.config of my normal F# library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283" newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, FSharp.Data does not support PCL libraries using profile 7. After changing my PCL project profile to 47 everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The MissingMethodException means exactly that (in terms of signature).

It sounds like your test code doesn't have a reference to the version of `FSharp.Data` DLL that your portable library is using.

The method signature for `asyncReadTextAtRuntime` was changed very recently, so you must reference the latest version in your test project.

See this GitHub commit, where the function was altered to take an additional parameter called `formatName`:

https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/commit/be3651f314b7a13b57a755a728287373adda775d#diff-a47e4306ce1338946e18435ee1e97c50R304

Comment: That does not seem to be the case as the FSharp.Data DLL file in the output folder is exactly the same as the one being referenced. I will try using a different PCL profile as the one I was using (new profile 7) is apparently not recommended: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/605

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and it was nothing to do with PCLs that I was aware. Adding an explicit binding redirect in the (C#) testing project for FSharp.Core made it go away (actually I had the same issue in Linqpad also)

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

(The testing project in C# has no direct FSharp references itself, other than what it inherits from the F# projects it's testing)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my version of the DLL to an earlier version.

In my case, I was attempting to use Type Providers in the FSharp.Data DLL.

I updated FSharp.Data to an earlier version and the error went away.